# SCADA Protocol - iec-104

Tags: scada

I am researching the IEC 60870-5 family protocols and in particular IEC-101 and IEC-104, for a university project.
Although purchasing the IEC-101 and IEC-104 standards, i am still left with fundamental questions that i can't seem to find answers for using Google. 
I am now focusing on understanding every Type Identification - its purpose, what its use, how to use it and draw a simple flow of each.
The standards doesn't supply the necessary information about the commands. 
Can anyone refer me to some website where these things are explained or any forum where i can ask question about these standards?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The companion standards (101 and 104) are incomplete (on purpose). You need at least section 5, a.k.a. IEC 60870-5-5, to understand the common flows. I tried to give a high level overview of the essential concepts in the README of my go implementation called "part5". https://github.com/pascaldekloe/part5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScadaBR has both protocols implemented, and is OpenSource... so feel free to tackle it and grab what you need from its source.

The good thing is that with some time, you can backward-engineer the IEC protocol. We use basically Luciol in our project. Check their site!
http://www.luciol.info/gb/support/support_download.html

You can get the codes from Sourceforge aswell
http://sourceforge.net/projects/luciol/

Regards,

Comment: http://www.luciol.info/gb/support/support_download.html is not available currently...

Comment: @snehalparmar Their web site is http://www.scadabr.com.br/. Their SF site is http://sourceforge.net/projects/scadabr/. However, both the web site and the manual available there are in Portuguese.

Comment: Now, based on ScadaBR it created project Scada-LTS.

Answer (score 4):

We developed a new implementation of IEC 60870-5-104 as a part of the Eclipse SCADA project. It available since the 0.2.0 M3 Milestone build. (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipsescada/news/2014/07/01/releases__0_1_3_and_0_2_0_m3.html)

You can also use it standalone without the other Eclipse SCADA dependencies (it has some dependencies on slf4j and netty and some other minor stuff).

Answer (score 0):

I found the book [Practical Modern SCADA Protocols DNP3, IEC 60870.5 And Related Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750657995) to be the best help out there the standard specification is a bit dry.

Look in Chapter 8 Fundamentals of IEC 60870-5, Section 8.5.2 ASDU Structure. It explains what the type ID is for and what they do.